# Expose ready-only data from Oracle DB to another Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, database-connection, replication

We have the following scenario:

We have an Oracle database in a secure zone (called ***inner***). We want to expose a subset of its data (which is represented by a view) to another Oracle database in another (unsecure) zone (called ***outter***).

We considered to do that with a database link from ***outter*** to ***inner***. However,  we have a very odd restriction:

> It's not allowed to make requests from ***outter*** to ***inner***. We are
>   only allowed to push data from ***inner*** to ***outter***.

A database link would violate this constraint as it would allow ***outter*** to make "requests" (SQL queries) to ***inner***. So we need another solution.

We already thought of a regularly triggered export from ***inner*** which gets imported in ***outter***. That would be OK, but we would prefer a solution which always provides up-to-date date in ***outter***.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define on both database extra users with minimum required privileges.

Define the **DB Link from INNER to OUTTER**.

Publish the data with this query connected on INNER, pushing the data to OUTTER via DB link

```
 INSERT into outter_table@outter_db
 SELECT * from inner_view
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! One more question: Let's assume we have 10 columns and 100 entries. We set up the link and do an `INSERT` for all 100 entries. Now an entry changes in ***inner***. Is there a smart way to publish/sync this change? Or do I need to write my own trigger which listens on an `UPDATE` and does the magic?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig there is no single antwort:). You may write own triggers, there is (change data capture)[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm] and other solutions. For a limited number of records, I'd prefer simple *full refresh*. Delete all records (via db link without commit) and re-instert them again. The big adavantage is that you never *miss* a change and the copy is always in sync.